# How to modify properly a pandas frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file that has this format:

```
E 7 FF 58322 000000 300 442 1165 +67875 +29
E19 FF 58322 000000 300 302 3027 +138703 +174
E 7 FF 58322 000000 300 442 1165 +67875 +29
```

As you can see the first and the third lines have `E 7` in the first column, i have tried to read the file into a pandas dataframe but it recognize `E 7` as two different columns, it is possible use a command that read `E 7` togheter?

I have tried this command:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ")
```

but it returns:

```
E   7     FF  58322  000000  300   442      1165  +67875  +29
E19  FF  58322      0     300  302  3027    138703     174
E   7     FF  58322  000000  300   442      1165  +67875  +29
```

and i would like:

```
E7     FF  58322  000000  300   442      1165  +67875  +29
E19    FF  58322  000000  300   302      3027  138703  174
E7     FF  58322  000000  300   442      1165  +67875  +29
```

is it possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are separating the data at every space using `sep=" "`. As there is a space between `E 7` those get separated too.

You need to modify your test-file and delete the spaces between `E`and `7` and you will get the intended result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your data. You need to clean it up before you start trying to read it into a `DataFrame`. Edit your txt file and remove the spaces between `E` and `7`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to preprocess the txt file and write to a temp file first.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('temp.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for reader in f_in:
        split = reader.split()
        if len(split) == 10:
            line = ''.join(split[0:2]) + ' ' + ' '.join(split[2:]) + '\n'
            f_out.write(line)
        else:
            f_out.write(reader)
```

Now read the temp file to a dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

Comment: ok, thanks it works, but why the fourth column that is 000000 becomes 0?

Comment: Because pandas is making assumptions that the column is a numeric. You can fix that with `data = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', sep=" ", header=None, dtype={3: str})`. Same thing applies to column at index 7 and 8 if you need the '+' symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not a csv (or other than comma 'separated value') formatted file, it is rather formatted as fixed width. Therefore, you need to use another function.

```
data = pd.read_fwf('./test.txt')
```

You will need to specify either the `colspecs` or `widths` argument to specify at which position each column starts.

*edit* as mentioned by Scratch'N'Purr the format is not exactly fixed with

Comment: Columns 8 and 9 aren't fixed width